# Unable to get webapi results

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I don't know how to see the get api results in the browser. I tried to get the response with this Url (`http://localhost:8269/api/getproducts`) but get an error:

```xml
<Error>
   <Message>
      No HTTP resource was found that matches the request 
      URI 'http://localhost:8269/api/getProducts'.
   </Message>
   <MessageDetail>
      No type was found that matches the controller named 'getProducts'.
   </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

```cs
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { ProductId=1,ProductName="samsung",ProductCategory="mobile",ProductPrice=7889 },
        new Product { ProductId=1,ProductName="nokia",ProductCategory="mobile",ProductPrice=7844 },
        new Product { ProductId=1,ProductName="lg",ProductCategory="mobile",ProductPrice=7887 },
        new Product { ProductId=1,ProductName="xiomi",ProductCategory="mobile",ProductPrice=7856 },
        new Product { ProductId=1,ProductName="htc",ProductCategory="mobile",ProductPrice=7833 }
    };

    public IEnumerable getProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try - http://localhost:8269/api/products/getproducts ?

Comment: yes i tried , getting error(The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.)

Comment: please edit your ajax method, You must have set `ContentType:application/xml` in ajax request?

Comment: how to set and where to write code for the same. i dont have ajax request. im just hitting in url.

Answer (score 3):

Your uri should be `'http://localhost:8269/api/Products'` *(with default routing that is...)*

When you're using Web API 2 your example should work fine with the above url.
When using Web API 1 though your method should just be called `Get()` or decorated with `[HttpGet]` attribute.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable getProducts()
{
    return products;
}
```

I suggest you look a bit closer at the basics of [asp.net web api](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513580/webapi-controller-actions-naming-convention#answer-33514206).

Comment: Also worth looking at the basics of resource naming in Rest  - http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html